# TradingView calculation how many bars is current bar higher or lower

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

What is the best way to calculate for example how many bars is the current bar high higher than the previous x bars?

I am using `max_bars_back = 5000`, so obviously it cannot be higher than 5000.

I suspect need to do something with `ta.valuewhen` or `ta.barssince`, but not sure how to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

This script determines the highest high within a lookback period, and when the highest high is broken, it displays a label with the bars that have passed from the previous highest high to the new.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Random', 'R', true, max_bars_back=5000, max_boxes_count=500, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

int Bars = input.int(20, 'Lookback')

float Max = ta.highest(high, Bars)
int Value = ta.barssince(high >= Max[1])
bool Change = if Value[1] != 0 and Value == 0
    true
if Change
    label.new(bar_index, high, 'Bars: ' + str.tostring(Value[1]), textcolor = color.red, size = size.normal)
barcolor(Change ?color.orange : na)
```